# Do I have a genuine GT frame, even though it's not engraved or stamped with the GT logo?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

How can I know whether the bike frame I have is a genuine GT? I found the serial number u31036009 on the bottom of the hub. It has no GT logo stamp or engraving anywhere on it. Could it still be genuine?

Comment: Pretty unlikely to be legit.  Someone's trying to flog off a bike-shaped bike and claiming its more than it is.  Is not impossible, but really unlikely.

Comment: Why don't you send an email to GT with that number and ask if it's theirs?

Comment: Just ran across this... Gt did make their earliest bikes without the engraving at the end of the top tube.

Comment: Do understand that "GT" is an old automotive term, meaning "gran turisimo" or some such, and being applied to a "road car".  From there it was no doubt applied to many bicycles before (and likely after) Gary Turner & co adopted it as their trademark in 1979.  (I'm a little surprised that it was even picked as a trademark, and their difficulty defending it may have contributed to the company's downfall in 2001.)

Comment: GT made BMX bikes over the course of well more than 3 decades. It's entirely possible they made some that didn't follow the same techniques or standards they used on 90% of their bikes. Most of their common models had specific tubesets that were very easily identifiable. Upload some pictures. I'd love to see if I can identify it.

Answer (score -2):

My awnser is that it COULD be a real gt,but probably one made strictly for racing(not publicly sold) or a prototype made by some one working for the company at the time. My big brother once had a profile complete bike(When they only sold bars to the public) because he was racing at the time and it had no serial numbers or logos/stickers. Its because it was a prototype and a R/D guy asked him to check it out and give him feedback about it. He then gave it to my brother when he was finished with testing. And when my brother told his friends they laughed at him saying he was lying because "They only sell handlebars". No body would believe him except me( I was there) so It could be some reason they didnt put logos on . Probably a prototype if not,could be a fake

Comment: That's a bit of a stretch of the imagination.  A fake or a concocted story is far more likely.   Remember, "there's a sucker born every minute."

Comment: Last sentence should be "probably fake, if not could be a prototype"

Answer (score -3):

GT definitely made BMX bikes in the late 70s and early 80s.  I very much remember deciding between a CookBrothers or a GT for racing when I was 10.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]. We recommend that new members take the [tour], and since you're answering see [answer] also.

Comment: I would normally say that this doesn't answer the question, but in light of the other poor answer it seems to be useful!

Answer (score -4):

I don't think gt ever made a bmx frame, but should it have, it would be one of a kind to celebrate something, for instance a racer that finished first. So they designed it for a purpose. I would advice you to get informed whether or not this is a gt bmx frame.

Comment: GT (Gary Turner) Bikes got there start in BMX

Comment: GT made tons of BMX bikes over the course of at least 3 decades.  I had GT BMX bikes back when I raced in the mid-80's all the way until I stopped riding freestyle BMX in the early 2000's.  They were known for it for a long time.